# How to sort results based on contained table value?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have Listings table that contains several Storages (which belongs to Properties). Can I sort Listing results based on `StorageInt11.val` at all?

```
public function findList(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->where([
            'category_id' => $options['for']
        ])
        ->contain([
            'StorageDate.Properties', 
            'StorageDecimal1.Properties', 
            'StorageDecimal2.Properties', 
            'StorageInt11.Properties', 
            'StorageVarchar255.Properties', 
            'StorageText.Properties'
        ])
        // The following does not work:
        ->order(['StorageInt11.val' => 'desc'])
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->toArray();
}
```

Should I maybe go to [Collections sorting](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#sorting) instead?

Comment: Whenever you have problems with associations, please mention the actual type of the association, ideally show the association setup code of the involved tables.

Comment: Like ndm said it may works but depends of association with StorageInt11 model. U can also use debugkit or a query looger to take a look about the generated query.